# How to suppress field and sum based on another column?

Tags: crystal-reports, sum

```
inv_num_vsl          sum              inv_num_car       sum                
 VI1001              72                 CI1001           29
 VI1002              72                 CI1001           29
 VI1003              72                 CI1001           29
 VI1004              72                 CI1001           29
                  ----------                         ------------
                     288                                 29
                  ----------                         ------------
```

From the example above i need to suppress duplicate data based on the inv_num. Eg for inv_num_vsl
all the inv_num_vsl are not the same so the sum no need to suppress and sum all, but in inv_num_car all 4 are the same so need to suppress the value to calculate only 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Right Click the field you want to duplicate:

> Format Object > Common > Suppress if Duplicate (checkbox)

If won't work then use [whileprintingrecords](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=182644)